# Looking for a jQuery slideshow for quotes that supports random

Tags: jquery, slider, quotes

I have looked at Quovolver, but don't think it supports random.  I want the order to be random so that when the page is loaded, the same quote isn't shown every time.

Comment: Why don't you just put all your quotes into an Array, shuffle the Array, and then use them in their new random order. This way you don't need to look for a slider that has a "random" flag...

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Cycles](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is a great plugin to show slideshows with multiple and custom effects and is not limited to just images.  This also has a random feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great plugin and super flexible.. Also supports random:
http://slidesjs.com/